# Irish Residential Property Price Register Data Plot Problem

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly, data-science, visualization, data-analysis

I have a very large dataset, which is over 500k observation, it contains counties of ireland and their residential property price register.
I have been working on this data with sampling method to avoid overfitting it caused me very slow results with Jupyter and plots.
My problem is when I use plotly and implement the code rather than dublin as county, all I see is empty plots, however I have got good(maybe problematic and dirty, but trying to be cleaned) dataset on it.\

I really could not understand what maybe the problem.

Here is the data if you are interested in.
https://www.propertypriceregister.ie/

Thanks.

```
#Exploring the data
print(df.head())
print(df.info())
print(df.describe())
```

```
`
The output: 

date_of_sale                                      address     county  \
386458   2019-09-02             DRUMANY, LETTERKENNY, CO DONEGAL    Donegal   
162739   2015-07-15  10 ABBEYBROOK GARDENS, KILBEGGAN, WESTMEATH  Westmeath   
105764   2014-05-15                 Parkroe, Ardrahan, CO GALWAY     Galway   
174554   2015-10-08                     DROMERK, DUNMANWAY, CORK       Cork   
327661   2018-08-31               8 HUNTSGROVE, ASHBOURNE, MEATH      Meath   

       eircode     price not_full_market_price vat_exclusive  \
386458     NaN  165000.0                    No            No   
162739     NaN   80000.0                    No            No   
105764     NaN   81000.0                    No            No   
174554     NaN   40000.0                    No            No   
327661     NaN  465000.0                    No            No   

                                  description property_size  
386458  Second-Hand Dwelling house /Apartment           NaN  
162739  Second-Hand Dwelling house /Apartment           NaN  
105764  Second-Hand Dwelling house /Apartment           NaN  
174554  Second-Hand Dwelling house /Apartment           NaN  
327661  Second-Hand Dwelling house /Apartment           NaN  
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 58558 entries, 386458 to 584214
Data columns (total 9 columns):
 #   Column                 Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------                 --------------  -----         
 0   date_of_sale           58558 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 1   address                58558 non-null  object        
 2   county                 58558 non-null  object        
 3   eircode                8256 non-null   object        
 4   price                  58558 non-null  float64       
 5   not_full_market_price  58558 non-null  object        
 6   vat_exclusive          58558 non-null  object        
 7   description            58558 non-null  object        
 8   property_size          5360 non-null   object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), object(7)
memory usage: 4.5+ MB
None
              price
count  5.855800e+04
mean   2.821019e+05
std    9.908397e+05
min    5.179000e+03
25%    1.250000e+05
50%    2.100000e+05
75%    3.200000e+05
max    1.074890e+08`
```

'''

```
# Filter to the selected counties
counties = ['Wicklow', 'Kildare', 'Meath', 'Cork']
df = df[df['county'].isin(counties)]



# Create subplots for each county
fig = make_subplots(rows=len(counties), cols=1, subplot_titles=counties)

# Loop through each county and add a trace to the corresponding subplot
for i, county in enumerate(counties):
    county_data = df[df['county'] == county]
    county_grouped = county_data.groupby(county_data['date_of_sale'].dt.year)['price'].median().reset_index()
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=county_grouped['date_of_sale'], y=county_grouped['price'], name=county), row=i+1, col=1)

# Update the layout and show the figure
fig.update_layout(height=800, width=800, title='Median Property Prices Over Time', showlegend=False)
fig.show()
```

'''

Comment: All the data is processed in the [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VGu9jYSCKF3c193hg9kPWji9w1E0C8l_?usp=sharing) environment. Although the graphs are not immediately generated due to the large amount of data, the intended graphs can be generated. It is not an empty graph; Colab will share it with you so that you can compare it with your code. If you see this link and comment on it, I will disable the link.

Comment: I'll take a look at it, thank you, i am in mobile now.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to work on Google Colab, will be a  nice experience I think so.